# Battery charger failure

Tags: voltage, current, temperature, layout, thermal

[image]

[image]

I'm using this [Battery Charger IC - MCP73831](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf).

I am using a SOT-23 package.

My input is 5V, the output Vbat charge regulated voltage on the Vbat pin is 4.2V and the maximum charge current is 340mA.

So, by calculation of power dissipation as per section 6.1.1.3 on page 18, it says that, for my condition,

Power Dissipation = (5V - 2.7V) * 0.34A = 782mW

Maximum junction temperature = (0.782 * 230degC/W) + 25deC (ambient) = 204degC approx.

Can you please check whether the layout is OK? Is grounding sufficient to reduce thermal dissipation?

My battery charger is burning and failing.

For the purpose of MOSFET, please see the below figure in this [App Note](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf)

[image]